# Check a object-string against a array of exceptions

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

I got a bunch of objects containing multiple string values. I want to manage the exceptions with a object/array consisting of multiple more and less known exceptions. Is there a simple way to get this to work? afraid my brain ain't made for this kind of problemsolving.

Example:

```
Exceptions =@{
                
                Known1  =  'Minor Error'
                Known2  =  'This Have We Seen Before'
                Known3  =  'I Remember This Issue'

                Special1 = 'Application malfunction'
                Special2 = 'Application malfunction severe!'
}


$AllCases = Get-Cases

Foreach ($Case in $AllCases){

                if ($Case.Name -match $Exceptions.Values.('^Known+[0-9]$')){'Do That again'}
                Elseif ($Case.Name -match $Exceptions.Values.Special1){'OBS! Do This Fast'}
                Elseif ($Case.Name -match $Exceptions.Values.Special2){'SEVERE OBS! do this faster!'}

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are the expressions supposed to be ANDed together, or ORed together? That is, does a "known" message have to match Known1, Known2, and Known3, or only at least one of them?

Comment: Only one of them :) @BaconBits

Comment: Does `$Case.Name` hold the exact value of the `Keys` on your Hashtable? i.e.: `$Case.Name` holds `Known1` or `Known2` or `Special1` etc.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon $Case.Name can be pretty much anything, but some of the cases contains the string-value of one exception. The goal is to have a simple array on the top of the script for any existing and future exceptions within the foreach-loop :) .

Comment: @Freshman not sure I'm following but a hashtable doesn't seem to be the best object type for your use case. You would use a hashtable when the value you get matches with the names of the keys. It might be better if you edit your question using pseudo code instead of PowerShell because the code you have there is pretty confusing and I don't think it displays accurately what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to create a script to identify incidents where `$case.Name` whatever that could be (subject of the incident?) matches with your map of words that are commonly found, which in turn points to a specific ***Error Code*** or ***Error Index***? If that's the case, It is probably better even though slower, to store a separate CSV file where you can add new ***Error Indexes*** and make your script read this CSV each time. In any case, I harcoded an example of how the CSV could look like and added some comments to guide you with the tought process.

```
$Exceptions = @"
Index,Error
Known1,Minor Error
Known2,This Have We Seen Before
Known3,I Remember This Issue
Special1,Application malfunction
Special2,Application malfunction severe!
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# I'll generate 500 random cases here mixing the words on Error
# I'll also added a IncidentNumber property becase I'm guessing you have something like that
$words = $Exceptions.Error -split '\s'
$AllCases = 0..500 | ForEach-Object {
    
    $ran = Get-Random -Minimum 2 -Maximum 10

    [pscustomobject]@{
        IncidentNumber = Get-Random
        Name = ($words | Get-Random -Count $ran) -join ' '
    }
}
```

#### Example of the cases created

```
PS /> $AllCases | Get-Random -Count 5

IncidentNumber Name                                                       
-------------- ----                                                       
    2043166219 Application This Remember Before                           
     837011116 malfunction Error Seen Have malfunction Issue Minor severe!
    2103904733 This malfunction We This I Have Seen Application           
     323914959 Minor This Issue Remember This Application Have Seen       
    1105202359 malfunction Seen We This I malfunction
```

Back to the script:

```
$result = foreach($Case in $AllCases)
{
    if($Exceptions.Error -match $Case.Name)
    {
        # Note: I'm using -match here instead of -in or -contains
        # because we want to partially match, considering that $Case.Name
        # could be a much longer string

        # $Exceptions array where the string in $Case.Name
        # matches any element of $Exceptions.Error
        $Exceptions.Where({$_.Error -match $Case.Name}) |
        Select-Object @{n='IncidentNumber';e={$Case.IncidentNumber}},Index,@{n='Status';e={'FOUND'}}
        continue
    }

    # If there are no matches you can use something like below, not sure
    # you have some sort of incident number or something short you can use
    # for those incidents not found :)
    $Case | Select-Object IncidentNumber,@{n='Index';e={$null}},@{n='Status';e={'NOT FOUND'}}
}
```

Since this is all random, it is possible there will not be any matches but in this run I got these results

```
PS /> $result | Sort-Object Status | Select-Object -First 10

IncidentNumber Index    Status   
-------------- -----    ------   
     505966803 Special1 FOUND    
     235217253 Known3   FOUND    
    1034830172 Known3   FOUND    
    1047600080 Special2 FOUND    
     481579809 Known3   FOUND    
    2131683661 Known2   FOUND    
     505966803 Special2 FOUND    
    1424263573          NOT FOUND
     249127953          NOT FOUND
     489126244          NOT FOUND
```